# Where is "PFFacebookUtils.framework" on CocoaPods repo?

Tags: parse-platform, cocoapods, parsefacebookutils

Does anyone know where to find the framework ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h in the new version of the SDK in CocoaPods?
Bolts are installed automatically but no ParseFacebookUtils

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this question on SO, your post in the google group, and a deflected issue in Facebook are the only indication that something is amiss. I wish there were a more reliable way to get Parse support. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/818703304829179/

Comment: `pod search Parse` doesn't show it - I expect someone will put it up soon.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The official pod is `Parse` not `Parse-iOS`, actually the iOS was just deprecated [a couple of days ago](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/issues/11294), to get things working just add `ParseFacebookUtils` to your pods file and update.

So this means your pods file should look like

```
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
```

save and update.

Comment: For the latest Facebook SDK4.0 it doesn't work. So I commented pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK' to allow pods to install older version of Fasebook SDK.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use the Facebook 4 SDK and the new version of Parse, you need the ParseFacebookUtilsV4 pod.

```
pod 'Parse',            '1.7.1'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4','1.7.1'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '4.0.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

**My Podfile:**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.1'

pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.20.0'
pod 'Parse', '1.5.0'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils', '1.5.0.1'
```

**My [Xcode's project name]-Bridging-Header:**

```
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.

#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

**Works like a charm using Xcode 6.1**

Answer (score 2):

## Facebook Update

> Facebook-iOS-SDK has been deprecated in favor of FBSDKCoreKit

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'SO-25575606' do
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An official podspec has been released for Parse, and the older one should be deprecated.

So now there's a `ParseFacebookUtils` pod as well.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Parse-iOS/1.2.21/Parse-iOS.podspec.json
https://github.com/hlung/podspec/issues/1

Comment: Thank you Fabian for advising me about that.

Comment: Oops! Doesn't work! Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Facebook-iOS-SDK (~> 3.17)` required by `Parse (1.2.21)`
- `Facebook-iOS-SDK (~> 3.9.0)` required by `ParseFacebookUtils (1.2.21)`

Comment: What this is telling you is that ParseFacebookUtils requires Facebook SDK 3.9, which is a bit outdated. Something else (possibly your Podfile) is requiring Facebook SDK 3.17. If you remove your explicit dependency on the Facebook SDK and keep ParseFacebookUtils, it ought to sort itself out. Or move ParseFacebookUtils farther up your Podfile. I've asked Parse whether depending on an older version of the Facebook SDK is deliberate.

Comment: Fabian, the problem was pod name. The official pod repo name is "Parse-iOS" and not "Parse" or "Parse-iOS-SDK". With the correct repo, works correctly.

Comment: @Fabian any news from parse as to whether the 3.9 is on purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure if @mergon was right in September of last year but as of now, the opposite seems to be true. I quote the description field of the 'Parse-iOS' pod: "Parse-iOS has been deprecated in favor of Parse"

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project > Select the project in Targets > Find by Other Linker Flags and add the `${inherited}` flag like print above.

[image: screen of flags]

Just compile and well done!